# Checking Whether a given date is in between two dates

Tags: angular

How to tell if a date is between two other dates in angular 2

I need to check a date which is in between the start date and the end date how can i check in angular 2?

Comment: What format is the date? Is it a UTC-string, is it an Epoch, is it an actual `Date` object?

Comment: it is actual date object

Comment: You can use `>` and `<` on date objects in pure javascript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really recommend to use moment.js (https://momentjs.com), it makes validation and calculation of dates much easier.
It has a built-in query method isBetween:
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/

Comment: Thanks :) problem is solved